# Rails gmaps4rails map - gmaps is not defined error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps

I'm trying to use gmaps4rails.  The client table is getting the latitude and longitude populated when I add a record. But, the map doesn't show anything.

From the browser console, I'm getting error: "Gmaps is not defined" on the 2nd line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
```

I have the javascript gmaps4rails folder with the coffee files and these lines in my application.js:

```
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.bing
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.mapquest
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.openlayers
```

My view code is:

```
  <ul id="markers_list">
  <%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"list_container" => "markers_list" } }) %>
  </ul>
```

My model has:

```
 acts_as_gmappable

 def gmaps4rails_address
  "#{address1}, #{city}, #{state}, #{zipcode}"
 end

 def gmaps4rails_infowindow
   "#{client_name}, #{address1}, #{city}, #{state}, #{zipcode}"
 end

 def gmaps4rails_sidebar
   "<span>#{client_name}</span>"
 end
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I've been looking at the browser console.

This is in the view page, where I'm trying to display the Google Map:

```
<footer>
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.8&amp;sensor=false&amp;client=&amp;key=&amp;libraries=geometry&amp;language=&amp;hl=&amp;region=" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/8/12/%7Bmain,geometry%7D.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.markers = [{"description":"Salt Lake County Headquarters, 2001    South State Street, Salt Lake City, UT, 84114","sidebar":"<span>Salt Lake County Headquarters</span>","lat":40.7267176,"lng":-111.8881423}, 
...(more data points right here)
Gmaps.oldOnload = window.onload;
window.onload = function() { Gmaps.triggerOldOnload(); Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
```

```
</footer>
```

I'm pretty sure that right after the first 2 script src=, there should also be:

```
<script src="/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js?1355589475" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js?1355589475" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But, these end up further down the page.  Seems to me that the 2 scripts aren't loaded before the gmaps is executed. So, I'm getting gmaps is not defined error.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  The following line of code was in my layout footer:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

Moved it to the header and Gmaps4rails started working.

Answer (score 1):

Well, why you render the map into markers_list?

```
<!-- render your map here -->
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"list_container" => "markers_list" } }) %>
<!-- and here you render the markers_list -->
<ul id="markers_list"></ul>
```

Are you shure that include `<%= yield :scripts %>` in